# Hide Apply label from SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint, label, hide, sharepoint-online, powerapps

Can we hide apply label input from SharePoint list form when you add a new item? I don't have a default value set by it, so I was wondering if someone managed to do this.
[Apply label picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jEVO.png)

Comment: Have you tried Julie's suggestion? Do you have further question?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have enabled any retention policies and label policies for your site, if true, this is by design and we cannot hide it.

[image]

[image]

If you want to hide it, disable these policies first to compare the result:

List from sites with no policies enabled:

[image]